# Unable to fetch XML child node in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I wrote the below code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;

use feature 'say';

my $request = "<request session=\"1\" timestamp=\"2\" crc=\"\"><get resource=\"CPX.Security.Session\"/></request>";
print $request, "\n";

my $dom1 = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $request);

my @titles = $dom1->getElementsByTagName("get");
foreach my $t (@titles) {
    print "$t\n";
}
```

I anticipate to get the ouput as the entire `<get>` node. The request XML that I am sending in is

```
<request session="1" timestamp="2" crc="">
  <get resource="CPX.Security.Session"/>
</request>
```

While the expected output is

```
<get resource="CPX.Security.Session"/></request>
```

I get the output as

```
XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x12e287c)
```

Can anyone help me out in fetching the required output. I am using the Dwimperl distribution of Perl.

Just to give a heads up, the above code is working in Strawberry distribution of Perl, however I need to get this work on the Dwimperl.

Comment: When I run your program I get `<get resource="CPX.Security.Session"/>` which is what I expect. Did you really mean you expected `</request>` on the end as well, because that isn't part of the `get` element? By the way, it is far easier to use single quotes for a string that contains double quotes; then you don't have to escape everything.

Comment: Thanks Borodin, It resolved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because you have an older version of `XML::LibXML` installed on the DWIM Perl system that doesn't stringify `XML::LibXML::Element` objects in the same way.

You should try upgrading your installation of the `XML::LibXML` module, but a workaround is to change

```
print "$t\n";
```

to

```
print $t->toString, "\n";
```